# css: overlapping responsive images with absolute position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs with a background-image were both divs have the same image but each with a different color. The images are waveforms

lets say image of div1 is grey and of div2 its green.

What has to be done is that the div with image1 is shown at start. div2 is not visible (width is set to 0).
Then something happens on the page and a progress has to be shown. 
Then the width of div2 is increased with Javascript depending on the progress and covers div1.

So the goal is that then depening on the progress X% of the space shows the green image and the rest the grey image

Therefore both divs need to be at the same position and need the same size of course.

Example of what it should look like:

[image]

I tried it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="left" id="container">
                    <div class="image original" style="background-image: url(/PATH/TO/IMAGE)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="image green" style="background-image: url(/PATH/TO/IMAGE_GREEN)">
                    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}



   #container{
        position: relative;

      .original {
         width: 100%;
        }

       .green, .blue{
          width: 0%;
       }
    }
```

With Javascript i would then increase the width of green. 
This would work already but my problem is now that the background image is larger then the div container. So not the whole image is visible in the div Container. 
I would have to add

```
background-size: 100% auto
```

to the .image class so that the whole image is contained in the div.

But if i do that the image would be responsive. So if i now increase the width of div2 from 0 to 100%, the background-image of div2 would not exactly overlap with the background-image of div1 during this procress as the whole image is squeezed in the smaller div2 container.

Then it looks like this:

[image]

But they need to match.

How could i achieve something like this?

Comment: Wait, what? Can you clear up the problem description?

Comment: i updated the question, i hope it is better to understand now :).

Comment: Maybe have everything full width, inside a container with `overflow: hidden`, and simply move your image instead of resizing it?

Comment: I think we need to see the images you're using, in order to understand what your concern is. Frankly, a more functional snippet is probably what's needed here. Too much is unknown.

Comment: the images are waveforms, i added them now

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a progress bar that looks like a background image colored in horizontally according to the percentage of progress complete. Rather than using 2 divs, it might be easier to use 1 div that has both a background image and transparent gradient, and animate the gradient like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="progress"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
  width:800px;
  height:150px;
  border:10px solid #555;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient( 
      to right,
      rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.45) 50%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0)
    ),
    url('https://placeimg.com/800/150/animals/grayscale');      
}
```

You could then re-assign the `background-image` property with new values for where the gradient should change to transparent using JS.

Full example using JS:
http://codepen.io/zesposi/pen/apyNGq

Comment: thank you, you are right from the principle but the overlapping image has to be identical as the background i updated my question and added an image